# How to set y_ticks at key points in stacked bar graphs instead of uniformly?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For the recipient's convenience I am trying to mark the y_ticks only where the bar charts split, but I can't figure it out. My code now:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
width = 0.3
ind = ['Label_1','Label_2']
y1 = [1000, 950]
y2 = [100, 120]
y3 = [40, 60]
ax1.bar(ind,y1,width = width,color='g',label='Fee_1')
ax1.bar(ind,y2,width=width,bottom=y1,color='orange',label='Fee_2')
ax1.bar(ind,y3,width=width,bottom=[i+j for i,j in zip(y1,y2)],color='brown',label='Fee_3')
ax1.set_yticks(y1+y2+y3)
ax1.set_xlabel('X Axis Labels')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y Axis Labels')
ax1.legend(loc="center")
```

When I plot this the labels have the values of the y values but they don't follow the stacked bar logic.

[image]

If anyone can help me figure out this puzzle that would be swell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your lists to arrays and concatenate the cumulative sums, and then set them as y-tick labels. I also used a single figure as

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

y1 = np.array([1000, 950])
y2 = np.array([100, 120])
y3 = np.array([40, 60])
ax1.bar(ind,y1,width = width,color='g',label='Fee_1')
ax1.bar(ind,y2,width=width,bottom=y1,color='orange',label='Fee_2')
ax1.bar(ind,y3,width=width,bottom=[i+j for i,j in zip(y1,y2)],color='brown',label='Fee_3')
yticks = np.concatenate((y1, y1+y2, y1+y2+y3))
ax1.set_yticks(yticks)
```

[image]